# Tomcat 6 constantly redirecting URL to old one

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat6, spring-webflow

I've done a lot of searching and not found anything like this, but I might not be using the right terms. My problem is this:

On a Tomcat 6 server, I originally deployed a Spring Webflow app with a context root of fred - to access it people went to myserver.com:8080/fred

The Spring code in that app changed all requests to have /spring after the context root - so the URL above would become myserver.com:8080/fred/spring - and this would bring up the index page.

That was all fine & dandy.

I rewrote the app to use Spring MVC instead, for reasons too boring to mention here, and as part of this removed the code that performed the /spring piece.

I am now trying to deploy it to the same Tomcat instance. It appears to deploy fine (after undeploying the old one).

However when I try to hit myserver.com:8080/fred to get the index page, it redirects to myserver.com:8080/fred/spring, and naturally this fails as that URL is not supported.

I've checked my config within the WAR, and also scanned through the following places in Tomcat:

conf directory
conf/catalina and subdirectories
webapps and subdirectories
work and subdirectories

I can't see anything referring to this /spring url rewrite. It does deploy and work successfully on my local version of Tomcat.

Could anyone offer any suggestions? All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like your browser cached the redirect. If your site at myserver.com:8080 used hard redirects (301 Moved Permanently) to send users from /fred to /fred/spring  your browser will remember that the next time you access the application. Try emptying the browser cache and trying again.

That would explain why everything is dandy on your local machine

Comment: The redirect was performed by Spring, internally to the webapp, but caching still might be the issue. I'll try again this evening. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: That's fixed it - thank you for your help. A bit embarrassing I didn't think of that.